# Hello "Route Settings in Widget AppState" / hello.dart ", null." I get the error. Can you change the code for me and tell me the truth?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I get the error:

> Another exception was thrown: Route Settings (" / hello.dart ", null) in the_Widget AppState."

Can you change the code for me and tell me the truth? What I did was change the name `main.dart` to another name. I get an error when I change the name of the page and call it. Example code:

https://github.com/albo1337/flutter_full_pdf_viewer/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart

> I/flutter (21501): Another exception was thrown: Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/hello.dart", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.

Comment: Don't rename the main.dart! Flutter needs that. Read an introduction to Flutter - Here is a good guide to writing your first app https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab

Comment: I get it, but this page needs a lot. Because the book has too many pdf pages to show. So I have to name and display a lot of books instead of main.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand. You have told us nothing about your project and you have not shared any code. If you just want to display a pdf then use pdf viewing package e.g https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pdfview

Comment: I want to tell you, when I add this flutter_pdfview main page, I'll have to change its name. So does not work.what can I do to make sure he doesn't get a mistake when he changes it?

Comment: share your code https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can run a specific file by mentioning its name.
If you are using command link run the command:

```
flutter run lib/hello.dart
```

If using .vscode the following configuration might help

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Flutter",
            "type": "dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "lib/hello.dart"
        }
    ]
}
```